# Reading Ubuntu package build logs

Tags: 16.04, lubuntu, compiling, mpd

I'm attempting to build [mpd](https://www.musicpd.org/) from source to replace Ubuntu's rather old distribution of mpd.  I've been having trouble with the recent upgrade to 0.19.12 in the Ubuntu distribution, and wanted to check if it was an old bug that has been fixed -- the current mpd is 0.20.15.

I can build mpd from source but now I'd like to install it using the same set-up that Ubuntu does, when its installed from the Ubuntu package.  So I've been trying to read the [package build log](https://launchpadlibrarian.net/298146918/buildlog_ubuntu-zesty-amd64.mpd_0.19.21-1_BUILDING.txt.gz) for the Ubuntu package and I've been having some trouble.

Where does one find in the package build log the items such as:

1. When the mpd user is created.
2. When the audio group is created.
3. When permissions are set on the new directories, and new directories created.
4. When the mpd daemon is set-up.

Where in the package log does one find that information?  When I "sudo make install" from source it does not do any of these things, so I'm assuming these items must be elsewhere.

A natural thing one might consider is to read the [mpd documentation](https://www.musicpd.org/doc/user/). As far as I can tell, it does not go into these kinds of details.